# JavaFX - How do I access the result(ObservableList) from a service?

Tags: checkbox, javafx, observablelist

How do I access the returned result from a service? The result is queried from the database and added to a ObservableList. I have a checkbox and wanted its value to depend on the result from the database.

How do I bind the checkbox so that its value(checked/unchecked) will depend on the rs.getString("studentForm137") field.

//cboxForm137.selectedProperty().bind(//I don't know the codes to bind checkbox);

Service

```
final Service<ObservableList<Student>> service = new Service<ObservableList<Student>>() 
    {
        @Override
        protected Task<ObservableList<Student>> createTask() 
        {
            return new Task<ObservableList<Student>>() 
            {
                @Override
                protected ObservableList<Student> call() throws Exception 
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 250; i++) 
                    {
                        updateProgress(i, 250);
                        Thread.sleep(2);
                    }
                    return student.display();
                }
            };
        }
    };
service.start();
```

Student Class

```
public class Student extends Person {

private SimpleStringProperty form137;
private SimpleStringProperty form138;
private SimpleStringProperty goodMoralCertificate;
private SimpleStringProperty birthCertificate;
private SimpleStringProperty highschoolDiploma;


public Student()
{
    super();
}

public Student(String lastName, String firstName, String middleName, 
        String cpNumber, String address, String dateOfBirth,
        String placeOfBirth, String emailAddress, String gender,
        String fathersName, String mothersName, 
        String form137, String form138, String goodMoralCertificate, 
        String birthCertificate, String highschoolDiploma)
{
    super(lastName, firstName, middleName, 
        cpNumber, address, dateOfBirth, placeOfBirth, emailAddress, gender,
        fathersName, mothersName);

    this.form137 = new SimpleStringProperty(form137);
    this.form138 = new SimpleStringProperty(form138);
    this.goodMoralCertificate = new SimpleStringProperty(goodMoralCertificate);
    this.birthCertificate = new SimpleStringProperty(birthCertificate);
    this.highschoolDiploma = new SimpleStringProperty(highschoolDiploma);
}

//form137
public String getForm137()
{
    return form137.get();
}

public void setForm137(String form137)
{
    this.form137.set(form137);
}

public StringProperty form137Property()
{
    return form137;
}

//form138
public String getForm138()
{
    return form138.get();
}

public void setForm138(String form138)
{
    this.form138.set(form138);
}

public StringProperty form138Property()
{
    return form138;
}

//goodMoralCertificate
public String getGoodMoralCertificate()
{
    return goodMoralCertificate.get();
}

public void setGoodMoralCertificate(String goodMoralCertificate)
{
    this.goodMoralCertificate.set(goodMoralCertificate);
}

public StringProperty goodMoralCertificateProperty()
{
    return goodMoralCertificate;
}

//birthCertificate
public String getBirthCertificate()
{
    return birthCertificate.get();
}

public void setBirthCertificate(String birthCertificate)
{
    this.birthCertificate.set(birthCertificate);
}

public StringProperty birthCertificateProperty()
{
    return birthCertificate;
}

//highschoolDiploma
public String getHighschoolDiploma()
{
    return highschoolDiploma.get();
}

public void setHighschoolDiploma(String highschoolDiploma)
{
    this.highschoolDiploma.set(highschoolDiploma);
}

public StringProperty highschoolDiplomaProperty()
{
    return highschoolDiploma;
}

@Override
public ObservableList display() 
{
    Connection c = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    ObservableList<Student> student = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    try
    {
        c = MySqlConnection.connect();

        String SQL = "SELECT * " +
                        "FROM students ";
        pst = c.prepareStatement(SQL);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next())
        {   
            student.add(new Student(rs.getString("studentLastName"), 
                                rs.getString("studentFirstName"),
                                rs.getString("studentMiddleName"), 
                                rs.getString("studentCPNumber"),
                                rs.getString("studentAddress"),
                                rs.getString("studentDateOfBirth"),
                                rs.getString("studentPlaceOfBirth"),
                                rs.getString("studentEmailAddress"),
                                rs.getString("studentGender"),
                                rs.getString("studentFathersName"),
                                rs.getString("studentMothersName"),
                                rs.getString("studentForm137"),
                                rs.getString("studentForm138"),
                                rs.getString("studentGMC"),
                                rs.getString("studentNSO"),
                                rs.getString("studentHSDiploma")));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error on Building Data");             
    }
    finally
    {
        try 
        {
            PublicClass.closeConnection(c, pst, rs);
        } 
        catch (SQLException ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(Student.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    return student;
}
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. You can get the result with `service.getValue()`, when the service call completes. Your service results in a list of `Student` objects: each one has a property corresponding to the value from the `studentForm137` database column. You would need a whole collection of check boxes, one for each student in the list. Additionally, the corresponding property in the `Student` class looks like it would be a string, not a boolean, which is required for the selected state of a check box. It would probably help to post your `Student` class.

Comment: "You would need a whole collection of check boxes, one for each student in the list" .. Thank you. I just realized that the checkbox state should only be changed when the user chooses a student at the tableview. Sorry, my bad.